# Actionscript Google Adwords Client Library

Tags: actionscript-3, google-ads-api, client-library

I have been searching for a Client Library for the Google Adwords (mainly for the Keyword Tool section) but to no avail. Does anyone know if this is even possible? I have seen all of the other client libraries; such as C#, Java, Javascript etc but no Actionscript.

I have read that Google do not support AS3, but this seems to be for the creating of Flash banners, which I do not want to do.

Anyone have any suggestions please ?
Regards
Anthoni

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't support an ActionScript client library, but there is an open source JavaScript library that you can try to port: http://code.google.com/p/google-api-adwords-js/

Comment: Do you have any idea when you will support Actionscript ?